# Probabilities of sequential measurments of spin 1/2 particle

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-spin, bells-inequality, bloch-sphere

I'm interested in checking why my working for the following problem does not agree with the expected result. In a section describing Bell's Inequality, the following sequence of measurments is outlined. Consider a spin $1/2$ particle. Also consider an eigenket of spin operator in direction $\hat{a}$ with negative eigenvalue i.e. the eigenket $|\mathbf{S} \cdot \hat{a}; - \rangle$. Given that we start in this eigenstate, the probabilty that a $\mathbf{S} \cdot 
\hat{b}$ measurement yields $+$, where $\hat{b}$ makes an angle $\theta_{ab}$ with $\hat{a}$, is given as:

$$|\langle \mathbf{S} \cdot \hat{b};+| \mathbf{S} \cdot \hat{a}; - \rangle|^2$$

If we consider $\hat{a}$ to be along the $z$-axis then let $|\mathbf{S}\cdot \hat{a};- \rangle = \dbinom{0}{1}$ and $|\mathbf{S} \cdot \hat{b}; + \rangle = \dbinom{\cos(\frac{\pi - \theta_{ab}}{2})e^{-i \alpha /2}}{\sin(\frac{\pi - \theta_{ab}}{2})e^{i \alpha /2}}$ where by symmetry we can take $\alpha = 0$ hence $$|\langle \mathbf{S} \cdot \hat{b};+| \mathbf{S} \cdot \hat{a}; - \rangle|^2 = \bigg|(\cos(\frac{\pi - \theta_{ab}}{2})~~\sin(\frac{\pi - \theta_{ab}}{2})) \dbinom{0}{1}\bigg|^2 = \sin^2\bigg(\frac{\pi - \theta_{ab}}{2}\bigg)$$ this result should be $\cos^2\bigg(\frac{\pi - \theta_{ab}}{2}\bigg)$. Is there anything clearly incorrect about my reasoning?

This is a pic of how I see it:

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: For $\theta_{ab}=0$, i.e. $a=b$, you have $|S.b; +\rangle=|S.a;-\rangle$.

Comment: @LucJ.Bourhis Yeah hence the overlap would be $1$. Which is consistent with my result since $\sin^2(\frac{\pi}{2}) = 1$.

Comment: But $|S.a;+\rangle$ and $|S.a;-\rangle$ shall be orthogonal.

Comment: Your definition of |S⋅b;+⟩ is wrong. You shout swap sin and cos, or equivalently, replace their (π-θ)/2 arguments by θ/2. As stressed by @LucJ.Bourhis, your definition is wrong for θ=0. It is the definition of |S⋅b;–⟩, not |S⋅b;+⟩

Comment: @FrédéricGrosshans See the picture for how I see what is happening. I don't see why $\frac{\pi - \theta}{2}$ should be replaced. This is the usual angle from the Bloch sphere definition. Could you elaborate on this please...

Comment: I would expect $|S.a;+⟩=|S.b;+⟩$ for $θ_{ab}=0$, but in your case (both equation and picture), it happen for $π–θ_{ab}=0$. It is not an intuitive notation, siince I would expect $θ_{ab}$ to be the angle between $a$ and $b$, not $π$ minus this angle, as per the (strange) convention you chose